# Get attribute groups from multiple attribute sets

Tags: attribute-set, magento-2.1.9, attribute-group

I'm trying to retrieve in some custom code the existing attribute groups from multiple attribute sets.
For this, I am using the `Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\GroupRepository::getList` method with search criteria builders and filters.
But I get a `Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException` with the message `No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue`.

This is my code:

```
private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
private $filterBuilder;
private $attributeGroupRepository;
public function __construct (
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeGroupRepositoryInterface $attributeGroupRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
) {
    $this->attributeGroupRepository = $attributeGroupRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
}

private function getExistingAttributeGroupIds($existingAttributeSetIds)
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters(
        [
            $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField('attribute_set_id')
                ->setValue($existingAttributeSetIds)
                ->setConditionType('in')
                ->create(),
        ]
    );

    $attributeGroups = $this->attributeGroupRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create());
    $attributeGroupIds = [];

    foreach ($attributeGroups->getItems() as $attributeGroup) {
        $attributeGroupIds[] = $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId();
    }

    return $attributeGroupIds;
}
```

I did some digging around and found that the issue comes from the `getList` method of the attribute group repository:

```
    $attributeSetId = $this->retrieveAttributeSetIdFromSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    if (!$attributeSetId) {
        throw InputException::requiredField('attribute_set_id');
    }
    try {
        $this->setRepository->get($attributeSetId);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('attributeSetId', $attributeSetId);
    }
```

This line `$attributeSetId = $this->retrieveAttributeSetIdFromSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);` ignores the fact that my filter has the condition `in` and expects it to be an integer. But based on my code it returns an array. So `$this->setRepository->get($attributeSetId);` tries to retrieve an attribute set with an id that is actually an array and it obviously fails.

So I have 2 questions about this:

1. Should I report this as a bug/inconsistency?
2. Is there a nice way to get the attribute groups via a single query for multiple attribute sets?  Please don't suggest calling `getList` for each attribute set (I have a lot of them so a foreach is not a nice solution).  Please don't suggest using attribute group collections instead of repositories. I already thought about the 2 solutions above. I want a clean, "magento2-way" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles on this....
In the version 2.1.9 this is not possible with one query.
I opened an [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11936) on the github repo and a [PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12105) to change this in one of the next versions.
hopefully it will get accepted.